In a pivot table - how to summarize by specific value
Here is a table:

I want to create a pivot table that will show me for each name, how much percent of "A" the name have, for this example:
Dan 100%
Ron 40%
Dafna 14.29%

Can you explain me how to do it (if this possible)?
Thank you!

When you create your pivot table, set the values to show as % of Row Total



Thank you! :-)
And how I remove the last column of total (all of it is 100%), there is a way to do it (instead of hiding it)?

@Yoar That's in the options dialog.
